# Protocol-less absolute URIs, with host, in HTML?

Tags: html, uri

I have seen some [pages](http://isgeolocationpartofhtml5.com/) that refer to what appear to be absolute URIs, with a host, but without a protocol. For example:

```
<script src="//mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My assumption is that this means 'use the same protocol as what we are on now', so the parent page will request `https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js` if its own protocol is `https`.

Is this syntax even correct? Part of a standard? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a "network path reference". The documentation for this can be found in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). Specifically, see section 4.2:

> A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is termed
>   a network-path reference; such references are rarely used.

And section 5.4:

> Within a representation with a well defined base URI of
>
> ```
>   http://a/b/c/d;p?q
> ```
>
> a relative reference is transformed to its target URI as follows...

```
"g:h"           =  "g:h"
...
"//g"           =  "http://g"
...
```

So a URI starting with a double slash is transformed to match the base URI. One use of this that I know of (in fact, the only use I've ever seen) is when using a CDN (for example, when including jQuery via the Google CDN). Google hosts a version on the `http` protocol, and another on the `https` protocol, and using this URI format will cause the correct version to be loaded, no matter which protocol you are using.

**Update** (having just found and read [this article](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/))

It appears that using this URI format throughout a page can prevent the "This Page Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure Items" error in IE. However, it's worth noting that this format causes files included via a `link` element, or an `@import` directive cause the included file to be requested twice. All other resources (such as images and anchors) should work as expected.